# GC overhead limit exceeded while starting eclipse after improper shutdown- GALILEO

Tags: java, eclipse, garbage-collection

I am having trouble with my eclipse (GALILEO). My computer shut down when elcipse was running. 
Now, eclipse is unable to open one of my workspace that was open during the shutdown. I can open other workspaces without problem, however , it seems like this particular workspace is corrupted. I have tried cleaning the workspace with `-clean` attribute, but it did not work.

When I try to open that workspace, I get error dialog  as :

[image: error while opening workspace]

When I check the meta data log as specified above, I see GC overhead error as below:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.instantiations.jlib.xml.XMLAttribute.<init>(XMLAttribute.java:64)
at com.instantiations.jlib.xml.XMLAttribute.<init>(XMLAttribute.java:83)
at com.instantiations.jlib.xml.XMLScanner.parseAttribute(XMLScanner.java:296)
at com.instantiations.jlib.xml.XMLScanner.parseAttributes(XMLScanner.java:249)
at com.instantiations.jlib.xml.XMLScanner.parseElement(XMLScanner.java:209)
at com.instantiations.jlib.xml.XMLScanner.parseNode(XMLScanner.java:122)
at com.instantiations.jlib.xml.XMLScanner.parseNodes(XMLScanner.java:93)
at com.instantiations.jlib.xml.XMLScanner.parseElement(XMLScanner.java:220)
at com.instantiations.jlib.xml.XMLScanner.parseNode(XMLScanner.java:122)
at com.instantiations.jlib.xml.XMLScanner.parseNodes(XMLScanner.java:99)
at com.instantiations.jlib.xml.XMLScanner.parseElement(XMLScanner.java:220)
at com.instantiations.jlib.xml.XMLScanner.parseNode(XMLScanner.java:122)
at com.instantiations.jlib.xml.XMLScanner.parseNodes(XMLScanner.java:99)
at com.instantiations.jlib.xml.XMLScanner.parseElement(XMLScanner.java:220)
at com.instantiations.jlib.xml.XMLScanner.parseNode(XMLScanner.java:122)
at com.instantiations.jlib.xml.XMLScanner.parseNodes(XMLScanner.java:99)
at com.instantiations.jlib.xml.XMLScanner.parseElement(XMLScanner.java:220)
at com.instantiations.jlib.xml.XMLScanner.parseNode(XMLScanner.java:122)
at com.instantiations.jlib.xml.XMLScanner.parseNodes(XMLScanner.java:99)
at com.instantiations.jlib.xml.XMLScanner.parseElement(XMLScanner.java:220)
at com.instantiations.jlib.xml.XMLScanner.parseNode(XMLScanner.java:122)
at com.instantiations.jlib.xml.XMLScanner.parseNodes(XMLScanner.java:99)
at com.instantiations.jlib.xml.XMLScanner.parseElement(XMLScanner.java:220)
at com.instantiations.jlib.xml.XMLScanner.parseNode(XMLScanner.java:122)
at com.instantiations.jlib.xml.XMLScanner.parseNodes(XMLScanner.java:99)
at com.instantiations.jlib.xml.XMLScanner.parseDocument(XMLScanner.java:78)
at com.instantiations.jlib.xml.XMLDocument.fromSource(XMLDocument.java:305)
at com.instantiations.jlib.xml.XMLDocument.fromFile(XMLDocument.java:209)
at com.instantiations.assist.eclipse.analysis.metrics.external.MetricsImporter.importMetricResultSet(MetricsImporter.java:72)
at com.instantiations.assist.eclipse.analysis.metrics.storage.StoredMetricResultSet.createData(StoredMetricResultSet.java:132)
```

Is there anyway to fix this issue? thanks in advance for any inputs.

Comment: Will it start specifying a new, empty workspace? If it will you can import the existing projects in to the new workspace if nothing else works.

Comment: I can actually delete the meta data or create new workspace as you said. But I am trying not to loose all the workspace's settings if possible. thanks for the input though.